# MySQL Join Query Autogenerate Serial Number

Tags: mysql, join

My Following Query gives the result according to my record but what i have the problem is my query is generating some different serial number .Anyways i need the serial number to start from 1 but this query is join query is shows different serial number like i can say during joining it skips the series .
Kindly help to generate the series from 1 to number of rows from db without skipping the series in between. Thanks in Advance

```
SELECT
    @a:=@a+1 sno,
    p.po_no as id,
    DATE_FORMAT(p.po_date, '%d-%m-%Y') as po_date,
    p.customer,
    p.cust_po as po_no,
    p.tot_ord_qty,
    DATE_FORMAT(p.delivery_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS delivery_date,
    p.dc_status,
    p.inv_status,
    p.tot_dc_qty,
    p.tot_inv_qty,
    COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(distinct d.dc_no SEPARATOR ', '), 0) as dc,
    GROUP_CONCAT( d.active SEPARATOR ', ') as status
FROM (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a, po_header p
LEFT JOIN dc_details d
    ON p.cust_po = d.cust_po
group by
    p.cust_po
```

Result:
[image: My Result SnipCut here]

Comment: What does `without skipping the series in between` mean here?

Comment: You are simulating row number here, but you don't have an `ORDER BY` clause.  That's wrong, or at least inviting problems.  Also, the numbers you get out may change as the data changes.  Perhaps an auto increment column would suffice for your needs.

Comment: As per your comment i added an order by clause for sno, but still i get the following result series ..6
9
14
21
22
26
30

Comment: Please edit your question and show us data, your expected and current output, and why the latter is wrong.  I'm guessing now that you want to generate a row number of a partition.  In this case, you would be ordering by two (or more) columns, not just one.

Comment: MR. Tim Biegeleisen, i have attached my result screenshot in this question kindly check and advice

Comment: Also check the sno column, it is getting skipped from 1 to 6 and then from 6 to 9 etc...

Comment: Don't mix cross products and joins in the same query. In fact, stop using cross products completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're skipping numbers is because of `GROUP BY`. Grouping is done *after* the serial numbers are generated, so it combines all the rows with the same `cust_po` and you only see one of the serial numbers.

Move the grouping into a subquery and add the serial numbers in the main query.

```
SELECT @a := @a+1 AS sno, t.*
FROM (SELECT @a := 0) AS a
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT p.po_no as id,
            DATE_FORMAT(p.po_date, '%d-%m-%Y') as po_date,
            p.customer,
            p.cust_po as po_no,
            p.tot_ord_qty,
            DATE_FORMAT(p.delivery_date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS delivery_date,
            p.dc_status,
            p.inv_status,
            p.tot_dc_qty,
            p.tot_inv_qty,
            COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(distinct d.dc_no SEPARATOR ', '), 0) as dc,
            GROUP_CONCAT( d.active SEPARATOR ', ') as status
    FROM po_header AS p
    LEFT JOIN dc_details AS d ON p.cust_po = d.cust_po
    GROUP BY p.cust_po
    ORDER BY p.cust_po) AS t
```